# fileSnapshots.bin file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I found out that in my Android Studio project. There is file called **`fileSnapshots.bin`** which is **90%** of the size of the whole project.

This is very annoying because I like making a copy of my project quite often. At the end there is a lot of room taken from my hard drive.

Does anyone know why this file takes so much? Can I just delete it from my copies without worrying?
The file is under the directory **`myproyect/.gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts`**.

Thanks!